# Mathematical reasoning behind pe=pa leading to maximum thrust

Tags: rockets, mathematics, thrust

I've been looking at both the thrust and thrust coefficient equations (below) and I understand that they will be optimum in a vacuum when $P_a=0$. But, I see in textbooks that $p_e=p_a$ corresponds to the maximum thrust. I've been told to take the partial of the thrust coefficient equation with respect to pe but this leads to the pa term disappearing. Is there some way to get pe/pa in this equation? Or is there a better way of clarifying mathematically why pe=pa leads to maximal thrust?

$$C_T=\frac{T}{A^*p_0}=\left\{\frac{2\gamma^2}{\gamma-1}\left(\frac{2}{\gamma+1}\right)^\frac{\gamma+1}{\gamma-1}\left[1-\left(\frac{p_e}{p_0}\right)^\frac{\gamma-1}{\gamma}\right]\right\}^\frac{1}{2}+\left(\frac{p_e}{p_0}-\frac{p_a}{p_0}\right)\frac{A_e}{A^*}$$

$$T=\left(A^*p_0\sqrt{\frac{\gamma}{RT_0}\left(\frac{2}{\gamma+1}\right)^\frac{\gamma+1}{\gamma-1}}\right)\left[\frac{2\gamma RT_0}{\gamma-1}\left\{1-\left(\frac{p_e}{p_0}\right)^\frac{\gamma-1}{\gamma}\right\}\right]^\frac{1}{2}+(p_e-p_a)A_e$$

Comment: Don't you get extra thrust if Pe > Pa cause then the right hand term in the thrust equation is > 0...

Comment: Do you know latex? This site supports it. I made a little enhancement to your question, now your task will be to do the same with that image formulas below. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the update with latex! In regards to your question @OrganicMarble, I was assuming the same thing, but I believe the left term varies in the opposite direction if pe>pa. I am trying to figure out how to prove this mathematically which is why I am trying to take the derivative and set it equal to zero to find the maximum point.

Comment: ...around so. :-)

Comment: Maybe there's some relation between $\gamma, p_a, p_0$ and $\frac{A_e}{A^*}$? From the purely mathematical point of view, you're right. If $\gamma, p_e, p_a, p_0, A_e, A^*$ are all independent, then the derivative over $p_e$ doesn't have to be 0 for $p_e=p_a$.